# Position of crease-point on right edge of $40\times40$ square upon folding top-left corner to midpoint of bottom edge?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving, origami

[image]

I was doing the following problem and my intuition was as follows. If point P touched Point R, the crease would be no distance from Q. When point P touches S, then the crease would be 20 cm away from point Q. So when point P touches point M, then the crease should be 10 cm away from point Q because M is the midpoint. But when I actually folded it out, I found the answer is actually 5cm from point Q.

How could I work this out without folding paper in an exam, what is the intuition behind it?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

The crease is the perpendicular bisector of $PM$, which is $AB$.

In the red right triangle, the width is twice the height, and the width is $30$.

So you can easily find the location of $B$.

Comment: Could you expand a little on why the width is twice the height, and why the width is 30.

Comment: @PeterPhipps Call the lower-left corner of the paper $C$. In right triangle $PCM$, the height is twice the width. The red triangle is similar to triangle $PCM$ (but smaller and rotated 90 degrees), so its width is twice its height. As for the width of the red triangle: from the left tip of the red triangle (which is the midpoint of $PM$), draw a line straight down - where does this line meet the bottom edge?

Comment: Thank you for that.